# Matching a file name using "like" wildcards

Tags: shell, automation, filenames, wildcard

I am trying to automate a process, but would like to make it more efficient and smarter. I am automatically downloading a file from my email daily, the email's naming convention is as follows:

pending_file_"current_date".xlsx (current_date as mmddYYYY, ie. pending_file_12082015.xlsx)

As expected, this folder will grow large with a ton of files named very similarly with only one change within the title, in this case the change will be the current date.

I am trying to make sure I grab the file corresponding to the current day, and this is what I have so far:

```
cd Pending_File
date=$(date.exe +"%m%d%Y") #assigns the current date to the date variable in the form of mmddYYYY

if [[ -f *"$date"* ]]; then
    scp pending_file_"$date".xlsx example@sample;
    echo "I have successfully completed today's file!"
else
    echo "Could not find today's file!"
fi
```

Currently, if I execute my code, it always executes the else statement, even though my pending_file folder contains a file named pending_file_"current_date".xlsx. My expectation is that date=12082015, which is also contained on the file pending_file_12082015, hence the if statement will return true as [ -f *"$date"* ] is able to match the date string within the file name.

Comment: What is this crazy shell that calls `date.exe` (smacks of Windows), yet thinks it can do clever bash-like things?

Comment: Hi Mark - not really sure if sarcasm, serious concern or something else. I am just trying to automate a daily task but my shell knowledge is almost none

Comment: It was a question. What shell is it?

Comment: Hi Mark - I am using Git Bash on a windows machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
if [[ -f "pending_file_${date}.xlsx" ]]; then 
   scp ...
fi
```

As will this:

```
for f in *$date*; do 
   scp "$f" ...
done
```